# A footnote in a note frame

Tags: beamer, footnotes

Whats is wrong by putting a footnote in a note frame?  In this example, the first footnote (in a standard frame) is correctly displayed, but the content of the second one (in a note frame) is invisible…

```
\documentclass[notes]{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}
  Here is a footnote\footnote{The FN's content!}
\end{frame}

\note{
  This also is a footnote\footnote{Hidden content! Haha!}
}

\end{document}
```

[image: Capture of the example]

Comment: You can use a `minipage`: `\note{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  This also is a footnote\footnote{Hidden content! Haha!}
\end{minipage}  
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beamer template `note page` doesn't print footnotes. So I searched for the code that prints the footnote on regular slides, and added it to the `note page` template using the `\addtobeamertemplate` macro (and I added some vertical space to have it aligned properly).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeameroption{show notes}
\makeatletter
\addtobeamertemplate{note page}{}
{%
  \vfill
  \ifvoid\beamer@footins%  
  \else%
    \begingroup
      \usebeamercolor*[fg]{footnote}%
      \footnoterule%
      \unvbox \beamer@footins%
      \global\setbox\beamer@footins=\box\voidb@x%
    \endgroup 
  \fi%
  \vskip.5em
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}
  Here is a footnote\footnote{The FN's content!}
\end{frame}

\note{
  This also is a footnote\footnote{Hidden content! Haha!}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]